# MYSQL Insert values from another table - trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have these tables in my database:

[image]

I want to add the registod and alarmes table one idRegisto .

The alarm table is populated automatically by a trigger. I would like to connect the two tables and the table alarmes populated idRegistos automatically by a trigger with the values ​​of table records.

Does anyone can help me please. 
I hope I have explained well my doubts

Thank you

[image]

My Trigger that populated table alarmes

```
DELIMITER $$
create TRIGGER alerta
BEFORE INSERT ON registos
FOR EACH ROW
begin
Set @comp=0;
Set @tempmax=0;
Set @tempmin=0;
Set @hummax=0;
Set @hummin=0;
Set @orvalho=0;


select lim_inf_temp, lim_sup_temp, lim_sup_humid, lim_inf_humid, lim_pt_orvalho into    @tempmin, @tempmax, @hummax, @hummin, @orvalho from sensores  where idSensor=NEW.idSensor;


Set @maxidAlarme=0;
if (CAST(NEW.Temperatura AS UNSIGNED)<@tempmin) then
SELECT MAX(idAlarme) into @maxidAlarme FROM alarmes;
SET @maxidAlarme=@maxidAlarme+1;
INSERT INTO alarmes(idAlarme,descricao_alarme) VALUES (@maxidAlarme,"ERROR");
end if; 


end $$;

DELIMITER  ;
```

Comment: Did you define referential constraint in `alarm` table on `idRegisto` column? How do you want to store it?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Not Yet. I can store as int...

Comment: Unless you add what you want on `idRegisto`, your posting is incomplete.

Comment: idRegisto will be automatically incremented. Is basically an id from table registos.

Comment: How do want to use it in `alarm` table? Using a trigger? And also see my first comment on top.

Comment: My idea was to change the existing trigger to fill idRegisto from table alarmes. idRegisto this must correspond with the idRegisto from table registos.   Sorry if I'm not quite explain my doubts.

Comment: In alarm table, do you want to use the same newly generated `idRegisto` of `registos` table?

Comment: Yes. This is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

> *In alarm table, do you want to use the same newly generated `idRegisto` of `registos` table? - Ravinder*
>
> *Yes. This is what i want. –  user3320956*

To insert the same newly generated `idRegisto` field value in `alarm` table,
Change part of your trigger body as below:

```
if ( CAST( NEW.Temperatura AS UNSIGNED ) < @tempmin ) then
     SELECT MAX( idAlarme ) into @maxidAlarme FROM alarmes;
     SET @maxidAlarme := @maxidAlarme + 1;

     SET @auto_idRegisto := ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
                              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'registos'
                                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() );

     INSERT INTO alarmes( idAlarme, descricao_alarme, idRegisto ) 
     VALUES ( @maxidAlarme, "ERROR", @auto_idRegisto );
end if;
```

Comment: Very Thanks for help.Could you tell me how to change the alarm table to take the idRegisto as a foreign key reference to the table registos please?

Comment: I'll test the code that you kindly gave me. But first I need to link the two tables by foreign key. That's why I asked for help it.

Comment: I will acept your answer but before I need to test.

Comment: Could you tell me how to change the alarm table to take the idRegisto as a foreign key reference to the table registos please?

Comment: In `Alarm` table add the `idRegisto` column with the same data type and size as in `registos` table and add referential constraint as `foreign key (idRegisto) references registos(idRegisto)`.

Comment: I try, but give me this Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_sensores`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-6c8_7120'>, CONSTRAINT `FK_alarmes1` FOREIGN KEY (`idRegisto`) REFERENCES `registos` (`idRegisto`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: when I insert on database give.me an error, dont add idRegisto on table alarmes...Error: Unknown column 'idRegisto' in 'field list'